# iOS home screen swipe functionality

Tags: ios, ios5, uiscrollview

On the *home screen* of an iOS device, let's say you have 3 "pages" of icons.

When you *swipe*, you are *forced* to land on a one of these "pages" (always a nearest neighbor).
I want to use this type of functionality in an app, but I don't want to *recreate* the code when something like this likely *already exists* in one of the many iOS frameworks. **What are the classes/IFB elements I should be looking at?**

*this is for an iOS 5 iPad project*

Comment: UIPageControl http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: UIPageControl is just for drawing the navigation dots at the bottom. You may want that as well if you're trying to replicate the home screen, but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIScrollview` has a `pagingEnabled` property that when set to `YES` forces it to stop on exact multiples of the view width when scrolled.

That's how the home screen works, and that's what you should use.

Comment: Wow- That's frickin awesome.  Did not know about that.  You just rocked my world